# DeflaterOutputStream won't output valid file

Tags: java, io

I'm using DeflaterOutputStream in combination with Buffered input and output streams, trying to just compress a simple file which I should be able to decompress with the second program (it also adds a number at the end of a line but this is irrelevant). However, it's not creating a valid compressed file. When I try to decompress it, it just creates a blank file. I think it might have something to do with flushing. Any thoughts?

```
public class Program {

static String inputFileName = "inputfile.txt";
static String outputFileName = "outputfile.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);
        BufferedInputStream inputBuff = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
        BufferedOutputStream outputBuff = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        DeflaterOutputStream deflater = new DeflaterOutputStream(outputBuff);
        int fileByte;
        while ((fileByte =inputBuff.read()) != -1)
        {
            deflater.write(fileByte);
        }
        deflater.flush();
        outputBuff.flush();
        fileOutputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}

public class Program2 {

static String inputFileName = "outputfile.txt";
static String outputFileName = "decoutputfile.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {    
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFileName);
        BufferedInputStream inputBuff = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);
        BufferedOutputStream outputBuff = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        InflaterOutputStream inflater = new InflaterOutputStream(outputBuff);
        int fileByte;
        int lineCount = 1;
        while ((fileByte =inputBuff.read()) != -1)
        {
            if (fileByte == '\n'){
                inflater.write(lineCount);
                lineCount++;
            }
            inflater.write(fileByte);
        }
        inflater.flush();
        outputBuff.flush();
        fileOutputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: At a glance, you can't just flush the stream, you need to actually close it with .close.